# extract values from nested list python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nested, mfcc

I have a pandas dataframe with Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients and they are nested in the column 'mfcc'.

Each row is a .wav file where somebody speaks a single word.

How can I extract each value and turn them into separate columns so I can analyse them?

I tried turning it into a dictionary and extract keys and values but when I tuned that back into a df i got the start result again.

Another problem I ran into is that the shape of the rows are not always the same. Most have a length of 99, but same are 98, 97 ,96, 56 or even 25 long, and that gave errors. How can i extract these values?

** edit **
i have added in the output if i print the file with numpy

[image: the df i got]
[image]

Comment: This looks like a problem you should fix upstream, i.e. you should not end up with this dataframe in the first place.

Comment: i have added a screenshot of the output when i print the numpy import of the file

Comment: Please construct a [MCVE] with input (sample) data and the desired output-df which we can copy-paste. Screenshots are not useful.

Comment: what does `np.shape(output)`
 give you?